# distinguishing duplicate rows in an sqlite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have a table with four columns username,product name,product price and a boolean column called item_paid.The same product name can be inserted as a duplicate entry into the table. But is there a way to distinguish one row from its duplicate?Or should i create a new column called ID to represent the uniqueness of each row?Please help.

Comment: There has to be a unique indentity in order distinguish two or more rows. It can be a primary key ID, or a composite key say (Username + productname) or any other.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should go back to basics with your database design. Instead of storing all of this in one table, why not split it into two or three?

For example:

```
User(User_ID, User_Name, User_Email,...)
Order(Order_ID, User_ID, Product_ID, Item_Paid)
Product(Product_ID,Product_Name,Product_Price)
```

You can use `User_ID` and `Product_ID` as foreign keys in the Order table.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

```
select product_name, count(1) cnt from table group by product_name having cnt>1
```

But recommended way is to create unique autogenerated id in your table.